# Solving PDE of type $x u_x + y u_y = f(x, y)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I solve the differential equation of the type 
$$
x u_x + y u_y = f(x, y)
$$
For example, let $f(x, y) = xy$. Using following method, I found $F(x,y) = F(x/y)$ is solution to homogeneous equation

[image]

What method can I use to find the particular solution of the given DE? When $f(x,y) = xy$, I put 
$$
u_y = cx \implies u(x, y) = cxy
$$
Putting this on DE, I found $c=1/2$. Is there general way to solve for particular solution of PDE?

Answer (score 2):

You can change to new variables $s=x/y$ and $t=y$ (for example).

(Let's say that we're looking for solutions in the region $y>0$, to avoid having to worry about division by zero.)

Then $u_x=u_s s_x + u_t t_x = u_s/y$ and $u_y=u_s s_y + u_t t_y = -u_s \, x/y^2 + u_t$, so your PDE becomes
$$
x \, u_s/y + y \, (-u_s \, x/y^2 + u_t) = f(x,y)
,
$$
i.e.,
$$
u_t = \frac{f(x,y)}{y}
.
$$
If you now express the right-hand side in terms of the new variables, you get something of the form
$$
u_t = g(s,t)
,
$$
and now you can simply integrate with respect to $t$, to get
$$
u(s,t) = G(s,t) + F(s)
,
$$
i.e.,
$$
u(x,t) = G(x/y,y) + F(x/y)
,
$$
where $G$ is the particular solution you asked about, and $F$ is the homogeneous solution that you already knew.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give an alternative derivation of Hans Lundmark's solution.

The Lagrange-Charpit equations for the PDE $xu_x+yu_y=f(x,y)$ are
$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{f(x,y)}. \tag{1}
$$
The solution to the first equality yields
$$
y=C_1x. \tag{2}
$$
As the second equation we take
$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{f(x,y)} \implies \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{f(x,y)}{x}. \tag{3}
$$
After replacing $y$ with $C_1x$ in $f(x,y)$, we can integrate $(3)$:
$$
u=C_2+\int_1^{x}\frac{f(s,C_1s)}{s}ds=:C_2+G(x,C_1)=C_2+G\!\left(x,\frac{y}{x}\right). \tag{4}
$$
It follows from $(2)$ and $(4)$ that the general solution to $(1)$ is
$$
u(x,y)=F\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+G\!\left(x,\frac{y}{x}\right), \tag{5}
$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.

In the particular case that $f(x,y)=xy$, Eq. $(4)$ yields
$$
G(x,C_1)=\int_1^{x}\frac{C_1s^2}{s}ds=\frac{1}{2}C_1(x^2-1)
$$
$$
\implies G\!\left(x,\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{y}{2x}(x^2-1)=\frac{yx}{2}-\frac{y}{2x}. \tag{6}
$$
Remark: the last term in $(6)$, $-\frac{y}{2x}$, can be absorbed by $F\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right).$